# What is the purpose of using 成语接龙 to learn 成语?

Tags: learning, teaching-methods

My son attends Chinese classes and one of the techniques they focus on is teaching the children to learn 成语接龙.

From my observation this allows someone to learn a large number of 成语 as it prompts you with the first character and the brain is quite adaptive in remembering sequences like this. However, what it doesn't seem to allow you to remember is meaning or meaning in context and how the 成语 is used in conversation.

In most cases if you search for 成语接龙 online you will be provided downloaded pages or sets that you can use to learn, but not the meaning of the individual 成语.

In Western countries idioms and sayings are usually learnt from reading, conversation and popular culture.

Is there a difference in the way that 成语 are learnt in Chinese that makes it important to learn in this way? What are the stated aims of using the 成语接龙 technique as I am aware that this also taught in (some) schools in China?

Comment: Comments have been purged. Please do not use comments to have an extended conversation. Please use chat instead.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose is to force one to recite idioms without explaining what they mean.

I believe this kind of **recitation** is a good way to learn language. Recite it first when we are ***young***; ponder about its meaning ***later*** when we have a sound background of related skills, such as logic, critical thinking. This belief is well backed by [him](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gu_Hongming), who learned English, German, French, Latin and Greek by recitation, allegedly. Recitation is also an important method to learn in [classic Chinese schools](http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E7%A7%81%E5%A1%BE).

Answer (score 1):

成语接龙 is a game for fun, which is used for opening our mind. You don't need to make sure the first Chinese character of every 成语 should be same to last end character, only same pronunciation is enough. Try your best to figure out 成语 which help you improve your mind and memory.

Answer (score 0):

Only East Asia Languages can do 接龙 (maybe.

成语接龙 is just a type of 接龙 that only allow use 成语.

And I don't think this game make significant effect on anything, it's just a game.

Of course children may have more enthusiasm than recite 《成语词典》

Answer (score -1):

It is just a Game, if you know more of 成语, the 龙 will go on. Actually, we do not use a lot of 成语 in daily life or modern novel.